# Unix awk what does f=1 do

Tags: unix, awk

So right now I am read some unix script and I am not quite sure if it does what I think it does.

```
foo=/some/directory/rules
awk '/^test=/ { print "test="foo; f=1 }
f==0 { print }
{ f=0 }' \
/some/other/directory/file
```

My guess is that this should not run ( because of "test="foo ), but it does - so I think the intend is that if a line out of '/some/other/directory/file' matches it gets written to '/some/directory/rules' with the praefix "test=", other wise it just gets printed on the console?

I am unable to find something in the man pages and the examples also don't use the f=? syntax

Comment: It is just assigning the variable `f` the value of `1`, it could be called anything. Also why do you think `"test="foo` would cause it not to run ?

Comment: This is not working because you need redirection to the file. Also `foo` is not set because it is a bash variable that has to be somehow provided to awk. For example, with `awk -v foo=$foo`.

Comment: @Jidder, thank you now everything makes sense :D

Answer (score 3):

Get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition by Arnold Robbins as you currently are very confused about awk syntax. The intent of the script you posted is to print the contents of `/some/other/directory/file` to stdout, except when a line starts with `test=` and in that case replace that line with one that says `test=/some/directory/rules`.

The more awk-ish way to write that would simply be:

```
foo=/some/directory/rules
awk -v foo="$foo" '{print (/^test=/ ? "test="foo : $0)}' /some/other/directory/file
```